# Does build include running Unit Tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, build

I used work on Java. I was using Ant/Maven for making the build process easier.

I used to write the unit tests in the JUnit framework. When I say `build` all unit test area lso used to run.

So there means, Build includes the compiling the source code and running the unit test against that compiled source code.

Now I started working with C++ on new project in Visual C++. Here, When I say `build`, Only source is compiled and linked with libs. But unit test are not ran.
So, now I got confused with actual definition of build process.

Does build process includes running tests also? Or it is just compiling and linking of source code?

Answer (score 0):

Ant and Maven "know" about unit tests. If an executable is marked as test, it will be run during the build process.

Visual Studio, AFAIK, does not have this concept. Even if an executable is written using some *Unit framework, Visual Studio will build it but not run it (by default). It is possible to run tests during the build process, but you need to add a post-build step to the test program's project to run the executable.

Disclaimer: The last version I used was VS 2003.NET; things might have improved (or gotten worse) since then.

Nowadays, I use the build tool with the greatest flexibility: `make`. In the project I'm currently working on, there's a build target named 'all' which builds every executable and test program, a target named 'check' which runs every test program (and builds them if needed), a target named 'coverage' which computes code coverage, and a target named 'run' which does all of the above. This way I get to choose what to run.

I hope that you can see from this that "what does the build process include" depends on how the build system is set up. There isn't a universally defined concept of "build process".